# CSS interfering with AdSense code

Tags: css, adsense, phpbb

I have adjusted my AdSense code (through Google's settings screen) to show large fonts, but the ads continue to be displayed in a small font.  I then realized that the AdSense code is enclosed in a  portion of my phpBB forum's header, which probably uses forced style settings from one of the forum's CSS files.

What can be added to the AdSense code to override font size settings just for the AdSense part?

Comment: Is it legal to modify the adverts?

Comment: Did you tried to force the css? Like `font-size: 26px !important;`?

Comment: !important is an admission of failure. Use higher CSS specificity instead.

Comment: It's not legal to modify the ads, and that's what my forum CSS is doing.  I am trying to keep it from being modified.